# How to convert the mat image to string (array2d<rgb_pixel>)?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, dlib

I created dll for [dlib](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html) for face landmark detection, in opencv we get the image in MAT but here in dlib the we get it by using array2d, so any one say how to convert the mat to array2d ??

The full code can be seen viewed [here](https://jayabalaji1394.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/code-used/)

Comment: Your title says convert to string, not to array2d.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [`cv_image`](http://dlib.net/imaging.html#cv_image), such as:

```
cv::Mat temp;
...
cv_image<bgr_pixel> image(temp);

// Detect faces 
std::vector<rectangle> faces = detector(image);
```

Also note that this just wraps the `cv::Mat` object and doesn't copy anything.  So `image` is only valid as long as `temp` is valid. This basically means you shouldn't modify `temp` while using `image`.